# Automatically insert a space between parentheses in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2

Is there some configuration or plugin I can use which would add spaces to the inside of parentheses when they're matched. Here's an example of what I'm trying to explain.

```
if (^) // ^ represents cursor position
if ( ^ ) // Where I want the cursor to be positioned.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can edit the auto-pair functionality.  I copied the following from "Key Bindings - Default" into "Key Bindings - User".  Add spaces in the `contents` values.  You can do something similar for square and curly brackets.  The first setting sets it for normal use.  The second sets it for when you have text highlighted.

```
// Auto-pair brackets
{ "keys": ["("], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "( $0 )"}, "context":
  [
    { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
    { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
    { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|;|\\}|$)", "match_all": true }
  ]
},
{ "keys": ["("], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "( ${0:$SELECTION} )"}, "context":
  [
    { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
    { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true }
  ]
},
```

**Edit**
To make the [key binding syntax specific](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=6867), add a line at the bottom of the `context` values.  You will have to find the syntax's `scopeName`.  For example html is `text.html` and sass is `source.sass`.

```
{ "keys": ["("], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "( $0 )"}, "context":
  [
    { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
    { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
    { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|;|\\}|$)", "match_all": true },
    { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.sass" }
  ]
},
```

Comment: In Atom, use https://atom.io/packages/bracket-padder